# How to use custom Add method for collection deserialization process?

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, deserialization, encapsulation

I have some class with tree node structure. It has Children property with read only collection type for hide direct changing of children and AddChild(...) method for control children adding.

```
class TreeNode {
   List<TreeNode> _children = new List<TreeNode>();
   public IReadOnlyList<TreeNode> Children => children;
   public string Name { get; set; } // some other filed 
   public void AddChild(TreeNode node){
      // ... some code
      _children.Add(node);
   }
}
```

And I need to provide deserialization for my class. I tried:

```
[Serializable]
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "node")]
class TreeNode {
   List<TreeNode> _children = new List<TreeNode>();

   [XmlElement(ElementName = "node")]
   public IReadOnlyList<TreeNode> Children => children;

   [XmlAttribute(DataType = "string", AttributeName = "name")]
   public string Name { get; set; } // some other filed 

   public void AddChild(TreeNode node){
      // ... some code
      _children.Add(node);
   }

   public static TreeNode Deserialize(Stream stream) {
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(TreeNode));
        var obj = serializer.Deserialize(stream);
        var tree = (TreeNode)obj;
        return tree;
   }
}
```

Of course, this doesn't work because IReadOnlyList has no Add method.

Is it possible to bind AddChild to deserialization process? And if 'yes' - How?

How to provide the same encapsulation level with deserialization ability?

Comment: Any particular why it's a `ReadOnlyList`? Why not just make it a `private List<T>` and then expose the `AddChild` method which can add to it?

Comment: You should look `ISerializable`  interface. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.iserializable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: @CihanYakar `XmlSerializer` doesn't care about `ISerializable`, and `IXmlSerializable` is very hard to implement correctly

Answer (score 0):

If this is `XmlSerializer`, then: no, you can't do that unless you implement `IXmlSerializable` completely, which is *very* hard to do correctly, and defeats the entire purpose of using `XmlSerializer` in the first place.

If the data isn't huge, then my default answer to any problem of the form "my existing object model doesn't work well with my chosen serializer" is: when it gets messy, *stop serializing your existing object model*. Instead, create a separate DTO model that is designed **solely** to work well with your chosen serializer, and map the data into the DTO model before serialization - and back again afterwards. This might mean using `List<T>` in the DTO model rather than `IReadOnlyList<T>`.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by adding a surrogate property to `TreeNode` that returns a surrogate wrapper type that implements both `IEnumerable<T>` and `Add(T)` using delegates provided to its constructor.  First, introduce the following surrogate wrapper:

```
// Proxy class for any enumerable with the requisite `Add` methods.
public class EnumerableProxy<T> : IEnumerable<T>
{
    readonly Action<T> add;
    readonly Func<IEnumerable<T>> getEnumerable;

    // XmlSerializer required default constructor (which can be private).
    EnumerableProxy()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException("The parameterless constructor should never be called directly");
    }

    public EnumerableProxy(Func<IEnumerable<T>> getEnumerable, Action<T> add)
    {
        if (getEnumerable == null || add == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        this.getEnumerable = getEnumerable;
        this.add = add;
    }

    public void Add(T obj)
    {
        // Required Add() method as documented here:
        // https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer%28v=vs.100%29.aspx
        add(obj);
    }

    #region IEnumerable<T> Members

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return (getEnumerable() ?? Enumerable.Empty<T>()).GetEnumerator();
    }

    #endregion

    #region IEnumerable Members

    System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Next, modify your `TreeNode` by marking `Children` with `[XmlIgnore]` and adding a surrogate property that returns a pre-allocated `EnumerableProxy<TreeNode>`:

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "node")]
public class TreeNode
{
    List<TreeNode> _children = new List<TreeNode>();

    [XmlIgnore]
    public IReadOnlyList<TreeNode> Children { get { return _children; } }

    [Browsable(false), EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never), DebuggerBrowsable(DebuggerBrowsableState.Never)]
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "node")]
    public EnumerableProxy<TreeNode> ChildrenSurrogate
    {
        get
        {
            return new EnumerableProxy<TreeNode>(() => _children, n => AddChild(n));
        }
    }

    [XmlAttribute(DataType = "string", AttributeName = "name")]
    public string Name { get; set; } // some other filed 

    public void AddChild(TreeNode node)
    {
        // ... some code
        _children.Add(node);
    }
}
```

Your type can now be fully serialized and deserialized by `XmlSerializer`.  Working [.NET fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/CuRp5x).

This solution takes advantage of the following documented behaviors of `XmlSerializer`.  Firstly, as stated in [Remarks for `XmlSerializer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer(v=vs.110).aspx#Remarks):

> The XmlSerializer gives special treatment to classes that implement IEnumerable or ICollection. A class that implements IEnumerable must implement a public **`Add`** method that takes a single parameter. The **`Add`** method's parameter must be of the same type as is returned from the **`Current`** property on the value returned from **`GetEnumerator`**, or one of that type's bases.

Thus your surrogate `IEnumerable<T>` wrapper does not actually need to implement [`ICollection<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92t2ye13(v=vs.110).aspx) with its full set of methods including [`Clear()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5axy4fbh(v=vs.110).aspx), [`Remove()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bye7h94w(v=vs.110).aspx), [`Contains()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k5cf1d56(v=vs.110).aspx) and so on.  Just an `Add()` with the correct signature is sufficient.  (If you wanted to implement a similar solution for, say, Json.NET, your surrogate type would need to implement `ICollection<T>` - but you could just throw exceptions from the unnecessary methods such as `Remove()` and `Clear()`.)

Secondly, as stated in [Introducing XML Serialization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/serialization/introducing-xml-serialization):

> XML serialization does not convert methods, indexers, private fields, or **read-only properties (except read-only collections)**.

I.e. `XmlSerializer` can successfully deserialize the items in a pre-allocated collection even when that collection is returned by a get-only property.  This avoids the need to implement a `set` method for the surrogate property or a default constructor for the surrogate collection wrapper type.